# Automated batch program maker

Tags: java, jquery, html, batch-file, weebly

I am making a website that has some of my files on it and it also has an open-source page so people can see my current programs that I am making.

I was wondering if maybe there is a way through HTML (maybe using some kind of "get" forum) to have several user input boxes on a page so there will be a "Title" box and then several other boxes where you can answer yes or no to have a certain option in your program.

So every time someone uses a box it adds code to a batch file like an "`Echo on or off box`" so if they choose yes it will say "`@ Echo on`", etc. Then they can download the finished file.

The website I am adding it to will be rhettsfiles.weebly.com but its not a huge feature I would like to add.

Comment: Ok guys, I told yall it would be broad because I am asking a question i have NO idea about. I have this question answered though so thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at StringTemplate? It's ideal for code generation:
http://www.stringtemplate.org/